# Paragraph justify with CoreText

Tags: iphone, ios, core-text

I have the following code to format a paragraph of text with CoreText.

```
(...)

CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)fontName,
                                         [self.fontSize floatValue], NULL);

CTTextAlignment alignment = kCTJustifiedTextAlignment;

CTParagraphStyleSetting settings[]={
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(alignment), &alignment},
};

CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(settings, 
                                           sizeof(settings)/sizeof(settings[0]));

self.attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         //The following line doesn't work!
         (id)paragraphStyle, kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName,
         (id)self.color.CGColor, kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,
         (id)fontRef, kCTFontAttributeName,
         nil];

CFRelease(fontRef);
CFRelease(paragraphStyle);

NSMutableAttributedString* aString = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""] autorelease];

(...)

[aString appendAttributedString:[[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attrs] autorelease]];
```

If I remove the following attribute pair (value/key), everything works (color, font, etc.).

```
(id)paragraphStyle, (NSString*)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName,
```

If I put this attribute on attrs dictionary, the program enters on an infinite loop when I use CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange.

What I'm doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE:** After Mattias answer I figured out that the code wasn't the problem. There were some HTML tags lost in the middle of the text (garbage) and for some reason the FrameSetter was getting lost and returning and empty range. When there's no HTML tags on text everything went ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect that `CTParagraphStyleCreate` returns `NULL` for some reason causing `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` to create an empty dictionary. But I can't see any error with your paragraph style setting.

Take a look at my [`CoreTextLabel.m`](https://github.com/wader/ios-misc/blob/master/CoreTextLabel/CoreTextLabel.m) class source which uses paragraph style settings.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see your code.I put a breakpoint and `CTParagraphStyleCreate` returns a value, not NULL.

Comment: I just noticed that when I enable that line,  `CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange` returns `CTFrame: visible string range = (14058, 0)`. This is an empty range as length ==  0. This is causing the infinite loop because I'm adding frame.length to the textPosition to process the visible columns.

Comment: Hmm ok. Can you make your example more complete?

Comment: Sorry, I figured out what was the problem. There were some HTML tags lost in the middle of the text (garbage) and for some reason the FrameSetter was getting lost and returning and empty range. When there's no HTML tags on text everything went ok.

Comment: Ah ok, don't know if my answer should be counted as accepted :) but thanks anyway. Maybe you could update your question with your finding?

Comment: Your answer was crucial to me to know that the code wasn't the problem. I saw very similar code on your class. After that I searched things that could be wrong on my string data and found the problem. I'll update the question with my finding. Thank you very much.